# Is there opposite of -y option for 'newrelic'?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, newrelic

I am making a `.sh` script that will automatically install New Relic's agent on Linux. During installation, there is a prompt if I want to use some extra features, but I don't want them, and I am not sure how can I write a script that will decline that part.

Command:

```
sudo NEW_RELIC_API_KEY=____NEW_RELIC_ACCOUNT_ID=___ NEW_RELIC_REGION=EU /usr/local/bin/newrelic install
```

If I add -y after install, it will accept everything, but I wanna the opposite thing.

You can see an example in the screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u8Tr.png)

Comment: `-y` isn't some universal Linux feature. Each application has its own set of arguments it accepts, based entirely on the code written in that application.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no opposite for -y

Answer (score 0):

Specify a "Recipe" or build your own using the [open install library](https://github.com/newrelic/open-install-library/blob/main/docs/README.md).

For Example: I was able to use this example [ubuntu.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/newrelic/open-install-library/main/recipes/newrelic/infrastructure/ubuntu.yml) file to run the install command silently (no prompts) on an ubuntu system.

`sudo NEW_RELIC_API_KEY=<MY_APIKEY_HERE> NEW_RELIC_ACCOUNT_ID=<MY_NRACCOUNTID_HERE> newrelic install --localRecipes ~/PATH_TO_LOCAL_RECIPE/ubuntu.yml`

The key parts of the ubuntu.yml are as follows:

```
install:
  version: "3"
  silent: true

  tasks:
    default:
      cmds:
      #  - task: assert_pre_req
      #  - task: cleanup
        - task: setup_license
      #  - task: setup_proxy
      #  - task: update_apt
      #  - task: install_gnupg
      #  - task: add_gpg_key
      #  - task: add_nr_source
      #  - task: update_apt_nr_source
        - task: install_infra
        - task: restart
      #  - task: assert_agent_started
      #  - task: assert_agent_status_ok
```

Note: since I had newrelic infra source/gpg I am able to skip these parts of the recipe.

*Edited to add example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).